# How to open Content Page in a new page

Tags: content-pages

this is my code, i want to open my Content Page ( InfoPrivacy.aspx ) in a new tab/page but cant make it work. Can you guys help thank you

```
<div id="Div1" runat="server" class="form-group has-error">
<div class="col-md-3">
</div>
<div class="col-md-9">
    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" />
    <strong>Dichiaro di aver preso visione e di accettare</strong>
    <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" NavigateUrl="~/Privacy.InfoPrivacy.aspx" Text="lprivacy d.lgs. 196/2003" />
    <span id="Span1" runat="server" class="help-block">asp:Label ID="Mod_InfPrivacy_lblError" runat="server" Text="***"></asp:Label>
    </span>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Use javascript to open the page in new tab.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following:

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" target="_blank" NavigateUrl="~/Privacy.InfoPrivacy.aspx" Text="lprivacy d.lgs. 196/2003" />
```

I have not been able to test it, but I think it will work.

If this doesn't work you could try to add a onClick function with Javascript.